# How to choose to which network doing port mapping

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container linked to multiple networks. As stated in the documentation the default gateway for this container is the first network in lexicographic order. This is working correctly.

Now I want to open a port from the outside world.

I use the `port` feature. When I look at my iptables what it seems to be doing is forwarding incoming packets to some random network. Not the first in lexicographic order.

This way, packets are coming in from given gateway and going out from a different one.

Do you know how I can specify, when I do:

```
port:
  - 80:80
```

how to specify which network am I forwarding to ?

EDIT: More information

So I have a container A belonging to A_net, B belonging to B_net and C belonging to both A_net and B_net.

The default gateway for C et A_net.

But in the docker-compose file. I say that port 80 should be mapped to port 80 for container C. Sometimes the iptable generated forward to B_net.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is it forwarding to a random network, or the docker-compose created network that is specific to your compose instance? See `docker inspect $containerid` for details on what network your container is on.

Comment: It is forwarding to a random network that the container belongs to (but not the first in alphabetical order).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for clarifying.